# EXTjs Changing 3 values to single array

Tags: arrays, extjs, sencha-architect

Trying to get familiar with extJS arrays and having some issues setting this up, I currently have the following code...

```
 if(!multiLine){
    phe = deviceType.search(check1);
    if(phe !== -1){phoneExists = true;}

    phe = deviceType.search(check2);
    if(phe !== -1){phoneExists = true;}

    phe = deviceType.search(check3);
    if(phe !== -1){phoneExists = true;}
}
return phoneExists;
```

Instead of simply checking 3 times separately, how can I check it all at once in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a Javascript question than extJS question. You could use `Array.some` method to check that at-least one element is found:

```
var devices = [check1, check2, check3]
var phoneExists = devices.some(x => deviceType.search(x) >= 0)
```

More on the [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: I get errors when I try to run that code through sencha architect, any idea on what needs to be changed?

Comment: var devices = [check1, check2, check3];
 var phoneExists = devices.some(x > deviceType.search(x) > 0);                                                      Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: It should be with `=>` not `>` where you have `pos.some(x` ...
var devices = [check1, check2, check3]; var phoneExists = pos.some(x => deviceType.search(x) > 0); This is ES6 Arrow function etc

Comment: What if I want to check if its == -1? rather than true or false?

Comment: `var phoneExists = devices.some(x => deviceType.search(x) == -1) `

Comment: Ahh I had a spelling mistake when I tested that, lol sorry thanks